# Excel 2010 cut and insert syntax

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to Excel VBA.I'm trying to feel my way through and I've hit a dead end.

I need to 
Input amount of devices delivered.
If all devices were not delivered, leave the row in place, update the quantities and change the row color.
If all devices were delivered, then cut (and remove the empty row) and insert (moving older entries down) at the top of a different worksheet.

I can't get the cut/insert to work correctly.

My current code:

```
Dim Models As Range    
Dim ModelCell As Range    
Dim RowNumber As Integer

For Each ModelCell In Models.Cells
                If ModelCell.Value <> "0" Then

                    CurrentCount = ModelCell.Value
                    TotalReceived = InputBox("How many were received?")
                    ModelCell.Value = CurrentCount - TotalReceived
                        If ModelCell.Value > "0" Then
                            Rows(RowNumber).Interior.Color = rgbAquamarine
                        End If


                Cells(RowNumber, 1).cut Worksheets("Completed_Orders").Range("3:3").Insert  'selects data and copies and pastes
                Rows(RowNumber).Delete 'Deletes empty row
                End If
            Next ModelCell
```

Comment: cut/paste as well as copy/paste in Excel VBA has very clunky syntax. My go-to solution is doing it manually under Record Macro, and then using the generated VBA code as a working template.

Comment: You can't do `...Cut [].Insert` on the same line. First, insert your line, then cut, then paste to the new line.

Comment: @BruceWayne You technically can put multiple statements on the same line by separating them with `:`, though I would not recommend it for readability.

Comment: @HaoZhang - Agreed...and also it doesn't look like OP is attempting that though.

Comment: You can first insert a blank row at "Completed_Orders", then Copy to that blank Row and finally Delete from the source.